# MySQL - Get similarity score from where two different rows meet same condition from two columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

What I want to do is generate a similarity percentage amount by comparing a ratings column from one table with the ratings column from another table.

However, this needs to be limited to instances where an id from one table matches an id in another table, is for a specific user and a rating exists in the ratings column from both tables.

For example, ***table1*** has the following columns and data:

```
   id   |   rate (out of 10)  
=====================
   1    |    8
   2    |    10
   3    |    5
   4    |    4
   5    |    0
   6    |    9
   7    |    8
```

And ***table2*** has the following columns and data:

```
 movid  |   userid   |   rating (out of 10)   
================================
   1    |     3      |    6
   2    |     2      |    10
   3    |     1      |    4
   4    |     3      |    7
   5    |     3      |    6
   6    |     4      |    8
   7    |     3      |    5
```

So lets say I want to use any rows where 'userid' = 3 and compare their 'rating' from ***table2*** to the 'rate' column from ***table1*** where 'rate' > 0 and id/movid from the two tables has the same number.

Using the example above, the results to compare should be limited to:

```
   id   |   rate   
=====================
   1    |    8
   4    |    4
   7    |    8

 movid  |   userid   |   rating   
================================
   1    |     3      |    6
   4    |     3      |    7
   7    |     3      |    5
```

Even though userid 3 had a rating for movid 5 in ***table2***, it had a 0 rate (no rating) for id 5 in ***table1***, so it will not compare those.

This would compare the ratings for each id/movid and then put it into an overall total. As the rating numbers are based on a score out of 10, I'm guessing the best way to determine the similarity percentage is to take the difference between each id/movid, subtract it from 10 to get the percentage number.

For id/movid 1, 'rate' in ***table1*** is 8 and 'rating' in ***table2*** is 6. The difference between those numbers is 2. We subtract 2 from 10, to get 80% similarity score for id/movid 1.

That would need to happen for each comparison and then total it all together.

So by my calculation, the similarity score for id/movid 1, 4 and 7 all combined would be 73% (rounded without decimals).

This total percentage amount is the end result I am trying to achieve. Can anyone help me out? I'm now bald after all of the hair I've pulled out trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(10-ABS(table1.rate-table2.rating))*10/count(table1.id)) as per FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.movieid WHERE userid=3 and table1.rate <> 0 GROUP BY userid
```

this will gives you what you need.

Comment: a bit change for negative values when it's greater then 10 will gives 100% right

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I can understand a lot of what you've put in there, and even though ensuring I have the right tables and columns typed in correctly, I am getting a resource id #25 error. Maybe I'm causing that somehow...

Comment: I still get the same resource id #25 error. There isn't anything else I need to do when calling on this query? This is how I've got it down:

<?php  include 'connect_to_db.php';

  $sql="SELECT ROUND(SUM(10-ABS(table1.rate-table2.rating))*10/count(table1.id)) as per FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.movieid WHERE userid=3 and table1.rate <> 0 GROUP BY userid";

  $result=mysql_query($sql);

echo $result;

?>

Comment: you can not echo result

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); and then print_r($row); you will get array

Comment: resource id #25 is not error its a resource of your result.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed that up. I'm no longer getting the resource error, now it returns the following: Array ( [0] => 90 [per] => 90 )

Comment: you can echo that answer by `echo $row['per']`.

Comment: Wow, excellent. I think that is working exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks a lot.

Comment: that's my job :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is:

```
SEELCT table1.id, table1.rate, table2.rating
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.movid
WHERE table1.rate>0 AND table2.userid=3
```

A simple INNER join plus filters in where clause to filter userid=3 and to show rates greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

Following is not the best solution, but it should work:

```
select ROUND(sum(tmp.similarity_score)/max(tmp.cnt)) as Total_similarity_score
from
(
select t1.id,t1.rate,t2.movid,t2.rating,
(10 - abs(t1.rate-t2.rating))*10 as similarity_score,
(@cnt := @cnt +1)  as cnt 
from t1
inner join t2
on t2.movid = t1.id
cross join (select @cnt := 0)r
where userid = 3
and t1.rate <> 0
)tmp  
;
```